# How to change computer name in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I found this answer:

```
Declare Function SetComputerName Lib "kernel32" Alias "SetComputerNameA" ( _
ByVal lpComputerName As String _
) As Long
```

but it dont work for me,
could you please show me how to change computer name in vb.net

Comment: "it dont work for me" - what actually happened? Could you show the code that attempts to use it?

Comment: Are you sure this is VB.NET and not VB 6 or VBA?  VB.NET usually uses DllImport rather than Declare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not simply paste `Declare`d definitions from VB6 to VB.NET.
In .NET you don't use `Alias "SetComputerNameA"` to call ANSI version of the function. The runtime manages this, and VB now supports both Ansi and Unicode.
VB6's `Long` matches to VB.NET's `Integer`.

```
Declare Auto Function SetComputerName Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpComputerName As String) As Integer
```